# How to write prometheus exporter to capture http request metrics for my application for prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I would like to write Prometheus exporter to gather HTTP request metrics for my application. The constraint is, I neither want to add any code to my app nor do I want to add any web server specific code i.e. apache or nginx. Is there any way that can work for the configured web server(either Apache or Nginx). I would like to use this exporter to send data to my Prometheus instance.

Answer (score 3):

Two options for NGINX:

1. Write access log, use [prometheus-nginxlog-exporter](https://github.com/martin-helmich/prometheus-nginxlog-exporter) or a custom exporter to parse lines.
2. (If  you use [OpenResty](https://openresty.org/en/) or built NGINX with Lua module) - use [NGINX lua module for Prometheus](https://github.com/knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus).

I personally use a self-written exporter and parse JSON log lines, but I plan to switch to Lua. The reason is that using logs has some reliability issues (file access problems, rotation, etc) and it can make the web server configuration messy.

Also, [NGINX ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/ddbb0be0a06e09d45735a2f3e1e8ee2e8946d0cb/rootfs/etc/nginx/lua/monitor.lua) has its own implementation of Prometheus metrics. You may want to take a hint or two from it.